# Is 'T' the same than CAST(X'54' as Text) in SQL? (SQLITE)

Tags: sql-injection

I am doing the room SQL Injection Lab and I dont understand something about task 6: Vulnerable Startup: Broken Authentication 3 (Blind Injection).  The room says that 'T' will be changed to 't' by the application. So, we need to change 'T' for  CAST(X'54' as Text). But, isn't it the same thing? If they are the same thing, how come the application behaves differently?

This is the link to the room https://tryhackme.com/room/sqlilab

[image]

Answer (score 1):

As the Lab states:

> The application will convert the username to lowercase for this challenge, which breaks the mentioned approach since capital T is not the same as lowercase t.

In this lab, it provides a method for getting around the application changing to lowercase by making the database interpret the letters using the CAST command to convert hex to the text character.

This can be shown by trying it with an uppercase T and noticing the Executed Query shows a lowercase t.

[image]

You need to send your blind inject guesses in hex and let SQLite interpret them with the CAST function.  The injection below was written `...=CAST(X'54') as Text`.  Notice how it's all lowercase in the executed query:

[image]

Without using the CAST you wouldn't be able to determine the value of the field (in this case password) if it contained any uppercase letters.

To do multiple letters, for example we know the password is going to start with `THM{`, you put their hex values in the same string: `(X'54484D7B')`

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer. If I understood correctly the application first converts the query to lower case and then the database interprets the cast function (already in lower case). And that's why it works, right?

Comment: Yes, the `x` in the cast function is declaring this is an integer in hexadecimal format; interpret it as text.  T, H, and M are 0x54 0x48, and 0x4D in hex.